# IIS 8.5 - Url Rewrite Rule for Http to Https only when is a certain domain

Tags: iis, iis-8, .net-4.8

there guys, this might be really simple but I'm not getting there.

So I have a Web Application hosted in an IIS 8.5 which has HTTP(80) and HTTPS(443).

I have to create a rewrite URL rule to make the HTTP requests go to HTTPS but only if the domain is coming from http://www.test123.com/

I managed to write the rule to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, it was very simple, but I'm not getting it to work the way I want it to work, which is only for some domains.

I used this guide to do the rule: https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/ even tho it is IIS 10, it worked pretty well for IIS 8.5

Does somebody know how can I write a rule for redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS only when it's coming from a certain domain?

Comment: You might get some hints from Mistake 1, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to judge host name so that it will only rewrite `http://www.test123.com`.

[image]

Comment: and do I put the rule before or after the HTTPS one? Or the order doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. HTTP change to HTTPS won't affect the domain.